# Passing @object into a rails partial render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a partial:

'profiles/_show.html.erb'

that contains code like

```
<%= @profile.fullname %>
```

I'm trying to render the partial but I'm not sure how to pass the @profile. I tried using local but apparently it sets 'profile' on my partial instead of '@profile'.

```
<%= render :partial => 'profiles/show', :locals => {:profile => @app.profile} %>
```

Is there anyway to pass it as @object instead of object, or is it designed this way?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Why is it so important that you use an instance variable(variables who's names begin with '@', eg: @object) in your partial? It's not a good habit to get into. Using instance variables in partials complicates the control flow, which facilitates bugs and makes reuse of partials more difficult. This [blog post](http://www.robertshowalter.com/articles/2007/07/24/dont-use-instance-variables-in-partials) explains the problem a little more in depth.

Really you have two options. The first option is the suggested solution.

1. Change all instance variables to a local variable and pass it to the partial with the locals argument of render.
2. Set the instance variable before the partial is rendered. Partials have access to all the instance variables that your controller sets.

Again instance variables in partials are bad. You should never set instance variables just because your partials are already written to use them. Rewrite the partial instead.

Comment: [An alternate link to a different article](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/27-replace-instance-variable-with-local-variable)

Comment: This^^ article appears to have moved here: http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/2010/07/24/replace-instance-variable-with-local-variable/

Answer (score 15):

Indeed, quoting [this](https://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/2010/07/24/replace-instance-variable-with-local-variable/) blog post you should know:

> A partial is a **reusable** view template, it allow you to modularize the
>   components which make up a particular page into logical, cohesive
>   pieces. When required data is not passed into a partial, it is often
>   difficult to reuse or change later.

The [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) site explains some simple use cases:

> You can also pass local variables into partials, making them even more
>   powerful and flexible. For example, you can use this technique to
>   reduce duplication between new and edit pages, while still keeping a
>   bit of distinct content ...

So in your specific case there is a simple and powerful way to do that

```ruby
<%= render partial: 'show', locals: {profile: @profile} %>
```

**Extra tip:**
Probably a partial named show is not a good option, give it a more meaningful name related to the thing you are trying to reuse. This sounds even more error/confusion prone in a RESTful scenario when you actually have a *show* method, so probably would be a *_show.html.erb* file and a *show.html.erb* file.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 6):

For Rails 3+, the answer to your actual question is:

```
<%= render 'profiles/show', :@profile => blah %>
```

Your partial will now see `@profile` locally.

I'm not saying this is a good approach.  I'm honestly not sure if this is ugly or not.  But it works.

Comment: This is generally **not** a good approach, but it can be helpful in some cases.  I'm working on a site now, where there is complicated dsiplay logic and we have a ton of partials so it was easier to have a localized global variable than worrying about passing it in to all the partials.

Comment: No, but it is the one accurate answer to the question he actually asked.  All the other answers are alternate approaches.

Comment: Fair enough, but sometimes alternative approaches are better than just answering the question asked.  Many times people aren't really sure what they need and just trying to understand how things work and best practices.  Like I said above, I've used this approach, but it's not a best practice.

Answer (score 1):

You could always do `@profile = profile` in the partial.

Comment: It's a bad idea to be setting instance variables in partials.  It can lead to all sorts of problems and will be a pain to track down.

Answer (score 1):

this is more simple

```
<%= render :partial => "profiles/show", :collection => @profiles %>
```

on partial _show.html.erb

```
<%= profile.fullname %>
```

hope helped

Comment: This only works if the caller of the partial has a collection of profiles *and* the caller wants to render the partial once for each item in the collection. The question has neither of these.